# Как очищать полностью папку с помощью schedule

Tags: php, laravel

Есть файл `Kernel.php` он срабатывает каждые 10 мин.

***Kernel.php***

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
  $schedule->call(function() {
    DB::table('remote')->delete();
  });
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы помимо чистки таблицы он еще чистил папку `public/upload/remotesr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалить папку:

```
File::deleteDirectory(public_path('upload/remotesr'));
```

Удалить содержимое папки:

```
Storage::cleanDirectory(public_path('upload/remotesr'));
```

Comment: Со одной стороны все работает спасибо. Но удаляется полностью папка а можно как то только содержимое?

Comment: @poznovashka обновил ответ